# Fullcalendar add icon or text inside an event

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to add an icon or text inside an event, but after search for documentation, I've no idea how to do.
For explane better what I need, I've added a pic:

[image]

I can't split an event because I need the ability to move that event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you need to put the icon on those exact spots where the X is? Are they meant to be related somehow to the time above them? What do these icons represent? It would help to know the context. You can certainly add more information into the display of an event using the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) callback, but you can't really relate it to specific points on the timeline.

Comment: Yes, i need to put icon/text exactly where the "X" is. Context: this sign stand for "milestone". It's related to day or time. In practice it indicates a significant event.

Comment: Are you trying to make like a gantt chart or something? Anyway as I said, you can't achieve that with any of fullCalendar's built in features. You can't detect the position of a middle point of an event relative to the timeline. You only get info about the start and end.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the milestones as separate events within the same resource - you can still customise their appearance to contain the icon instead of the standard text. But it means you can place it on the right time. That's about as close as you'll get without completely rewriting fullCalendar's view engine

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to achive a simple "gantt calendar". Fullcalendar have all I need, but this... I'm wandering around.

Comment: ok well I've suggested the closest way to achieve what you want, there's not really anything else I can do to help you.

Comment: And I thanks you, the problem is one resource can have more than one event, so could be a bit messy using that way.

Comment: I don't know if something like this would work better for you? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart . Or if you Google "JavaScript Gantt chart visualisation" there are one or two other options around by the look of it, maybe you will be able to look more closely at them